# Collapsing a multi-index to an index following an unstack

Tags: python, pandas

How do I manipulate the following data frame, such that the columns are an index, rather than a multi-index:

```py
df = pandas.DataFrame([
    {'col_1': 'A', 'col_2': 'A', 'value': 1},
    {'col_1': 'A', 'col_2': 'B', 'value': 1},
    {'col_1': 'A', 'col_2': 'C', 'value': 1},
    {'col_1': 'B', 'col_2': 'A', 'value': 1},
    {'col_1': 'B', 'col_2': 'B', 'value': 1},
    {'col_1': 'B', 'col_2': 'C', 'value': 1},
]).set_index(['col_1', 'col_2']).unstack()
```

This gives:

```
      value      
col_2     A  B  C
col_1            
A         1  1  1
B         1  1  1
```

However, I'd like:

```
col_1     A  B  C
A         1  1  1
B         1  1  1
```

I know I can use `.loc` to get half way there:

```py
df.loc[:, 'value']
```

This gives:

```
col_2  A  B  C
col_1         
A      1  1  1
B      1  1  1
```

However, I can't see the next step.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are seeing are the names of the `pandas.Index` objects that reside in the `index` and `columns` attributes of the dataframe.  To keep the one you showed, you want to get rid of the name of the `pandas.Index` object in the `columns` attribute.

```
df.value.rename_axis(None, axis=1)

       A  B  C
col_1         
A      1  1  1
B      1  1  1
```

---

To take it a step further, you really need to remove the `col_1` from the `index` using `reset_index`

```
df.value.rename_axis(None, axis=1).reset_index()

  col_1  A  B  C
0     A  1  1  1
1     B  1  1  1
```

Answer (score 1):

That is dataframe `unstack` you can change to `series`

```
df = pandas.DataFrame([
    {'col_1': 'A', 'col_2': 'A', 'value': 1},
    {'col_1': 'A', 'col_2': 'B', 'value': 1},
    {'col_1': 'A', 'col_2': 'C', 'value': 1},
    {'col_1': 'B', 'col_2': 'A', 'value': 1},
    {'col_1': 'B', 'col_2': 'B', 'value': 1},
    {'col_1': 'B', 'col_2': 'C', 'value': 1},
]).set_index(['col_1', 'col_2']).value.unstack()
df
col_2  A  B  C
col_1         
A      1  1  1
B      1  1  1
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do:

```
df.columns = [e[1] for e in df.columns.values]
print(df)
```

**Output**

```
       A  B  C
col_1         
A      1  1  1
B      1  1  1
```